# What's the difference between uniform-cost search and Dijkstra's algorithm?

Tags: graph, artificial-intelligence

I was wondering what's the difference between *uniform-cost search* and *Dijkstra's algorithm*. They seem to be the same algorithm.

Answer (score 72):

> Dijkstra's algorithm, which is perhaps better-known, can be regarded
>   as a variant of uniform-cost search, where there is no goal state and
>   processing continues until all nodes have been removed from the
>   priority queue, i.e. until shortest paths to all nodes (not just a
>   goal node) have been determined

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform-cost_search#Relationship_to_other_algorithms

Comment: The two pages on wikipedia have now been merged.

Answer (score 41):

Dijkstra's algorithm searches for *shortest paths from root to every other node* in a graph, whereas uniform-cost searches for *shortest paths in terms of cost to a goal node*.

Also, uniform cost has less space requirements, whereas the priority queue is filled "lazily" opposed to Dijkstra's, which adds all nodes to the queue on start with an infinite cost.

Comment: Why are the nodes added with an infinite cost in Dijkstra?

Comment: @HappyFace In a real world implementation, one would only add the source node and add further nodes as they are discovered. It's also possible to just add all nodes at the start and only update their distances as they are discovered. 
I would however not call that a characterstic feature of djikstras. It's an implementation detail with no influence on the complexity or result and the essence of the algorithm remains the same either way.
Note that only the former method can process infinte graphs and the space consumption can be a lot lower, which is why it's more practical.

Answer (score 27):

Compilation of other answers by NotAUser, dreaMone and Bruno Calza

Dijkstra's Algorithm finds the shortest path from the root node to every other node. uniform cost searches for shortest paths in terms of cost from the root node to a goal node. Uniform Cost Search is Dijkstra's Algorithm which is focused on finding a single shortest path to a single finishing point rather than the shortest path to every point.

UCS does this by stopping as soon as the finishing point is found. For Dijkstra, there is no goal state and processing continues until all nodes have been removed from the priority queue, i.e. until shortest paths to all nodes (not just a goal node) have been determined.

UCS has fewer space requirements, where the priority queue is filled gradually as opposed to Dijkstra's, which adds all nodes to the queue on start with an infinite cost.

As a result of the above points, Dijkstra is more time consuming than UCS

UCS is usually formulated on trees while Dijkstra is used on general graphs

Djikstra is only applicable in explicit graphs where the entire graph is given as input. UCS starts with the source vertex and gradually traverses the necessary parts of the graph. Therefore, it is applicable for both explicit graphs and implicit graphs (where states/nodes are generated).

Comment: Why wouldn’t Dijkstra work with an implicit graph?

Comment: The definition of Dijkstra requires that all costs of nodes are set to infinity at the start of the algorithm. So, you need to know all your nodes first. In implicit graphs, nodes are generated at each step so, you can't know all the nodes before starting the algorithm.

Answer (score 5):

There's a paper that talk about the similarities and differences about both.

http://www.aaai.org/ocs/index.php/SOCS/SOCS11/paper/view/4017/4357

Answer (score 1):

The main difference is that *Dijkstra's algorithm* is defined when numbers of vertices is finite. It says to put all the vertices in a queue. But we can not put all the vertices in a queue when numbers of vertices tend to infinite. *Uniform Cost Search* is defined in a situation like this, where numbers of vertices are unknown.