# Can search algorithms (BFS and DFS) also be used to get the shortest path?

Tags: algorithm, search, depth-first-search, breadth-first-search

In my AI course I learned about BFS, DFS and UCS. In my algorithm course I learned Dijkstra's algorithm.

Do we apply search algorithms like BFS and DFS only to determine if a specific node  exist or not OR does it also give the shortest path like Dijkstra's algorithm?

Comment: bfs/dfs does not give you the shortest path to the discovered node at least because it does not take into account an edge weight

Comment: even if we consider weight=1 for all edges, assume undirected graph with 3 nodes, A, B, C, and 3 edges, (A,B), (A,C), (B,C). You start DFS on A, then let's assume you will discover B, then you will discover C. But the shortest path from A to C is not 2, it is 1, because there is an edge (A,C).

Answer (score 1):

Dijkstra's algorithm is just a generalisation of BFS - BFS is conceptually the same as Dijkstra's if all edge weights are equal to 1.

**BFS** (Breadth-First Search) will give you the shortest (as in lowest-cost) path if all edge weights that are equal to 1, but won't (necessarily) otherwise, since the order in which it explores nodes doesn't depend on the edge weights at all.

**DFS** (Depth-First Search) will not necessarily give you the shortest path because it just explores one arbitrary path at a time - maybe you get lucky and that path is the shortest path, but generally it won't be. It will give you the shortest path in a tree, but that's only because there's exactly one path to any given node.

**UCS** (Uniform Cost Search) [works very similarly to Dijkstra's algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12806452/whats-the-difference-between-uniform-cost-search-and-dijkstras-algorithm) and will also return the shortest path, but to a single goal node rather than to all other nodes.

### Example

For the below graph, let's say we're starting from A and going to E.

```
    A 1 C 1 D
    O---O---O
100 |       | 1
    O-------O
    B  100  E
```

Both BFS and DFS can or will return the more expensive path (A-B-E = 200 instead of A-C-D-E = 3).

BFS will visit B (A-B) and C (A-C), and then E (A-B-E) and D (A-C-D). At this point it will stop because it already reached the goal, and return the longer path A-B-E.

DFS can start off arbitrarily visiting either B or C. If it visits C first, it will return the shortest path A-C-D-E, but if it visits B first, it will explore A-B-E and return that longer path.

Comment: Can you explain about UCS ?